# how to get the value of a dropdownlist to the controller in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i am trying to get the value of my dropdownlist to my controller with Jquery, everything i try , gives me a null pointer for the second parameter. Here is my code :

this is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $("#ddl").on("change", function () {
    var selectedID = $("#ddl").val();
    this.href = this.href.replace("idhotel", selectedID);
    });
});
</script>
```

this is my ActionLink:

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Voeg toe aan winkelwagentje", "Winkelwagen", new { id = Model.Id, hotelid="idhotel" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

And this is my Action in the Controller:
(just header)

```
public ActionResult Winkelwagen(int? id,int hotelid)
    {
        
        Console.Write("Please give me the hotelid: " + hotelid);
Return View();


}
```

and here is the dropdownlist:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddl", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "Text", "Value"), "Select")
```

output dropdownlist:

[image]

error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'hotelid' of non- > nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult > Winkelwagen(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' > in 'TreinRittenVives.Controllers.ReizenController'. An optional parameter must > be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
> Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Can you show us the output html of the dropdown? Also, any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Did you try to log the values of selectedID and href in your jquery function ? What do you get ?

Comment: the console gives me the id, but there is something wrong with te replacement:

Comment: : Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Second parameter is not nullable. How you get null value for it? Also this.href in drodown change? Dropdown has not href. You should select your actionlink then set its href

Comment: how do i select my actionlink and set it to the href? never worked with this befor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your script `this.href` means your select element which ID is`#ddl` and `select` can't contain `href` attribute. so you can do something like

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#ddl").on("change", function () { 
    var newHref=$("a").attr("href").replace("idhotel", this.value);       
    $("a").attr("href",newHref);         
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: idhotel keeps sending a null to my controller

Comment: @peukertje. please `console.log($(a).attr("href").replace("idhotel", selectedID));` and see what value is printed in your browser. and sow me

Comment: it gives me the id of the model that was posted in the url

Comment: reizen is the controller name, boeken is the action name and 6 is the id name

Comment: there is still a little problem, if i change it  after my first choice, he still takes the value of the first change

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter is not nullable on the controller.

it should be...

```
public ActionResult Winkelwagen(int? id, int? hotelid)
```

If you want it to be a nullable type.

Regards

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#ddl").on("change", function () {
    var selectedID = $("#ddl").val();
    $(a).prop("href", $(a).prop("href").replace("idhotel", selectedID));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Error:**

Server Error in '/' Application.
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'hotelid' of non- > nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult > Winkelwagen(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' > in 'TreinRittenVives.Controllers.ReizenController'. An optional parameter must > be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

**Reason for error:**

The above error will occur most of the time in development and the main reason for the above error, is when we write a action method in the controller , we will specify the parameters as non nullable that is without the question mark in the datatype 
**ex.**

Public void test(int a , int b)

The value must be passed, if we couldn’t pass for some reason then the above error will occur.

**Solution to Error:**
The best solution for the above problem is make the parameter as nullable

Nullable ex:

Public void test(int? a,int? b)

**More info**:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/